# Is it possible to have xerror increased in a tree using rpart?

Tags: r, cross-validation, cart, rpart

I am new to R and rpart package. When I plot the tree using rpart:

```
> temp_control <- rpart.control(xval=10, minbucket=2, minsplit=4, cp=0.0001)
> dfit <- rpart(Target~., data = temp_data, method = 'class', control=temp_control)
> printcp(dfit)
```

Then I get :

```
          CP nsplit rel error xerror     xstd
1 0.00189329      0   1.00000 1.0000 0.040140
2 0.00172117     28   0.92255 1.0861 0.041708
3 0.00114745     32   0.91566 1.0947 0.041861
4 0.00098353     41   0.90534 1.1102 0.042133
5 0.00086059     48   0.89845 1.1274 0.042433
6 0.00043029     62   0.88640 1.1515 0.042849
7 0.00034423     75   0.87952 1.1635 0.043055
8 0.00028686     80   0.87780 1.1687 0.043142
9 0.00010000     89   0.87263 1.1807 0.043346
```

Why does xerror increase with the growth of a tree? Do I need some more adjustment of the parameters? Also, I am wondering how the root node error is calculated. Is it only related to a certain dataset? Does it have any relationship with parameters setting?

Actually, I tried "anova" method although my response variable is categorical (Y/N). I just changed them to 0/1 and run "anova", then I can get :

```
         CP    nsplit rel error  xerror     xstd
1   3.1473e-02      0   1.00000 1.00025 0.037408
2   1.1506e-02      1   0.96853 0.97164 0.035479
3   5.6396e-03      2   0.95702 0.96528 0.035172
4   4.6137e-03      3   0.95138 0.96970 0.035029
5   4.4412e-03      6   0.93754 0.97246 0.035019
6   4.3751e-03      7   0.93310 0.97006 0.034915
7   4.1352e-03     10   0.91997 0.97109 0.034912
8   3.5702e-03     11   0.91584 0.97316 0.034847
9   3.0148e-03     14   0.90513 0.96819 0.034671
10  2.5334e-03     15   0.90211 0.96872 0.034725
11  2.2789e-03     16   0.89958 0.96959 0.034753
12  2.2342e-03     17   0.89730 0.97437 0.034829
13  1.8732e-03     18   0.89507 0.98647 0.035104
14  1.8401e-03     19   0.89319 0.99511 0.035199
```

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: It is possible. It means that any tree other than the root node is overfit; that is, your best tree has no branches.

Answer (score 1):

`xerror` means cross validation error. Why validation error increase? Because over fitting. This is exactly what cross validation used for. In your case, it makes perfect sense because, more splits in `rpart` tree means more complex model, which is more possibilities for over fitting.

Try `plotcp` function to see, when to overfit and select the "right" tree size.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem where my Cross validated error was increasing with every split. It turned out that I had lot of rows with default value. Post removing those I got better splits. I suggest have a good look at your data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to take the dependent variable out of "data = temp_data."

Comment: This is not correct.  The `data` argument should be the whole data set.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. The solution is to balance the count of event and count of non-events in the training set. RPART is very sensitive to the ratio, as far as xerror is concerned.